# How to initialize PHP GET variable to avoid PHP undefined index notice

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code that binds PHP GET value to MYSQL query:

```
$STH->bindValue(':category', $_GET['category']);
```

Now I'm receiving a PHP notice in my error_log:

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: category
```

I can't just declare $_GET['category'] or I will remove its value.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just wrap that line of code in an if statement to check if it's set:

```
if(isset($_GET['category'])) { 
    $STH->bindValue(':category', $_GET['category']);
}
```

Comment: Won't you get an error if you don't bind `:category` (in the case of category not being set)?

Comment: i use a check condition on the mysql query itself so that if category not set, don't include it in the query...so no error would appear

Comment: Good point - there needs to be a safe default set - would hope the rest of the code handles this given it's already going to be undefined as is...

Comment: Brill - in that case my suggestion should help stop your error log filling up nicely.

Answer (score 1):

Verify the key exists in the array, or supress errors **from the get superglobal**

```
if (!empty($_GET['category']))
    $STH->bindValue(':category', $_GET['category']);
else
    $STH->bindValue(':category','');
```

OR

`$STH->bindValue(':category', @$_GET['category']);`

You generally don't want to @ the whole line, or you may miss important errors.

Comment: I won't downvote because the first part of your answer is acceptable but please don't advocate the use of `@`. You should try and handle the error, not suppress it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ternary operator for this, but you will need to define a default value

```
$STH->bindValue(':category', isset($_GET['category']) ? $_GET['category'] : '');
```

Which is short for

```
if (isSet($_GET['category']))
    $STH->bindValue(':category', $_GET['category']);
else
    $STH->bindValue(':category', '');
```